# How do I pass a parameter from a LINQ query into a SQL View?

Tags: c#, linq, variables, parameters, view

I have a view on SQL that I am using to pull data. However, I keep getting a timeout error the last few days. The view is pulling data for all the ID's instead of one by one. So my idea is to pull the data per ID. How do I pass the ID into the View using a parameter / declaring a variable?

I just need a simple example.

We don't want to change the timeout limit as it's not a permanent solution. The data is growing every day, so it's not a reasonable change.

Comment: Apart from ideas, scenarios and ideal solution, where is the code that you've tried and it did not work or gave an unexpected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass parameters to a view. For this purpose, you can use a stored procedure instead.

Use the link below to create your stored procedure:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/162/how-to-create-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameters/

And if you want to use your stored procedure in linq, please read this link:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/using-stored-procedure-in-linq/